# Effect not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site, there are icons on a "dock" and when the user hovers over one, a short description "falls" from the icon. Here is the CSS for the effect, which works fine in Dreamweaver, but doesn't seem to work in any browser.

```
<style>
    .css3-notification {

    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;     
    font-weight: bold;

    -webkit-animation: ease-in 800ms;
    -moz-animation: ease-in 800ms;      
    -o-animation: ease-in 800ms;
    animation: ease-in 800ms;
}

    @-webkit-keyframes ease-in {
    from   {top: -40px; opacity:0;}
    to     {top: 0px;}
}

    @keyframes ease-in {
    from   {top: -40px; opacity:0;}
    to     {top: 0px;}
}
</style>

<div class="dock" id="dock">
 <div class="dock-container">

 <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="../Site images/Bill@2x.png" alt="home" /><span class="css3-notification"><font size="3">IDEATION</font><p>Put your idea on paper</p></span>

 <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="../Site images/Jesus@2x.png" alt="contact" /><span class="css3-notification"><font size="3">TEAM</font><p>Build a team</p></span>

 <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="../Site images/Financestat@2x.png" alt="music" /><span class="css3-notification"><font size="3">MVP</font><p>Track and compile data from testing</p></span>

 <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="../Site images/Dollarbag@2x.png" alt="video" /
>  <span class="css3-notification"><font size="3">Funding</font><p>Find Funding</p></span>

 <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="../Site images/Spaceship@2x.png" alt="history" /><span class="css3-notification"><font size="3">LAUNCH</font><p>Successfully Launch</p></span>

</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: you haven't closed your `<a>` in your HTML given..please correct the errors..and, if you can, please share a fiddle with us..

Comment: Where is your Javascript/jQuery code?

Comment: also for the hover to work, we have a `:hover` CSS pseudo selector, which i doesnt see in your style..

Comment: Please also note that usage of the `<font>` tag is something from the last millenium.

Comment: I could be wrong but `ease-in` might be a reserved string as it refers to a specific timing function.

Comment: Both animations start at an opacity of 0, and you do not change that in the `to {}` part. So it should stay fully transparent, rendering it invisible.

Comment: Where can I host the site to show how the effect is incorporated? If it isn't apparent, I'm a novice developer but so far everything I've written works.

Comment: For example on codepen.io

Comment: Thanks connexo, I just did it on tumblr quickly...
 http://startadc.tumblr.com/

Comment: The idea is that the little bio that comes from hovering over the icons, should fade in and down.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how exactly are you trying to do this, but here is a simple trick that may be helpful. Initially have your .css3-notification to display:none. Then on hover of the parent .dock-item, display the child .css3-notification; like below:

```
a.dock-item:hover .css3-notification
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Note that the above example will only help you display/hide the tooltip. You may need to add the styles you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks King.. I'll give it a shot.